# How do I pass a variable in stored procedure in the alias part

Tags: sql-server, function, date, variables, stored-procedures

I have declared this :

```
SET @30days = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @reference_date)
```

I want to pass this 30 days variable to the following query:

```
SELECT
    SUM((CASE 
            WHEN pcc_view_ar_aging.effective_date >= @reference_date   
                 AND pcc_view_ar_aging.effective_date < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @reference_date) --'2010-09-01 00:00:00:000'   
                 OR (pcc_view_ar_aging.effective_date >= DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @reference_date)   
                     AND pcc_view_ar_aging.transaction_date < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @reference_date)   
                 AND pcc_view_ar_aging.transaction_type <> 'C')  
               THEN pcc_view_ar_aging.amount 
               ELSE 0 
         END)) AS sum_bucket_0, 
    SUM((CASE WHEN pcc_view_ar_aging.effective_date >=  dateadd(month, -1, @reference_date)   AND pcc_view_ar_aging.effective_date <  @reference_date   THEN pcc_view_ar_aging.amount ELSE 0 END)) AS sum_bucket_1,
```

How can I pass

```
@30days = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @reference_date)
```

days in place of `sum_bucket_1` so that when this runs it should take value from 30 days.

Thank you

Comment: 30 days and 1 month are NOT the same thing. Be precise - understand that difference. 30 days before March 31 is a different value than 1 month before March 31. Your code already subtracts 1 month from your variable so it is not clear what your goal is and how it would be different from your existing code.  Perhaps you just want to replace that existing dateadd expression with your variable?

Comment: Actually that wont affect the procedure in this case, but we just need that column name to be defined dynamically. sum bucket should end up giving me a date

Comment: No idea what that means. If you want the name of the column (as opposed to the value computed and included in the resultset) to be dynamically generated, then you need to use dynamic sql.

Comment: ok, can you please tell me what do i have to use